# Getting an ID or other handle for a file chooser dialog box in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

There are lots of posts on SO about how to work with a file chooser in Selenium, but they all seem to think you have a reference to an element representing the file chooser dialog, often because you know the element's ID. How do you find this? My normal method, using "Inspect Element," doesn't work, because there's no way to turn Inspect Element on with the file chooser dialog up.

The page in question is images.bing.com. The file chooser comes up when you click on the camera ("Search using an image") and then click browse.

Here's what I've tried. I wrote this function to get a list of  all visible elements so that I could look at which elements are visible after I click the link to bring up the file chooser but not before. This process identifies three such elements, but none of them has an ID when I run `elem.get_attribute("id")` or `elem.get_property("id")`.

```
def get_visible_elements(self):
    result = set()
    for elem in self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("*"):
        try:
            if elem.is_displayed():
                result.add(elem)
        except StaleElementReferenceException:
            pass
    return result
```

Comment: what do you get in the result?

Comment: The _file chooser dialog_ is native element and _Selenium_ won't be able to interact with it

Comment: @MosheSlavin, `get_visible_elements` returns 788 elements, 3 of which weren't visible before I clicked "Browse." None of those 3 have IDs, and I'm not sure what other queries to run on them.

Comment: @DebanjanB, I hope that's not the case, but it may be. There are other answers on StackOverflow where people are able to interact with these dialogs using `send_keys`.

Comment: @kuzzooroo `send_keys` can only be invoked on relevant `<input>` tags with _type_ attribute set as **file** nothing else

Answer (score 1):

Following the steps given [in this Selenium tutorial](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/faq.html#how-to-upload-files-into-file-inputs), to upload a file, you're not looking for the dialog element itself, but rather the `<input type="file">` HTML element that generates it.

To find that, usually you can inspect the button that brings up the file selection dialog. If not, inspect something near it and look at the nearby HTML.

In this case, for images.bing.com, I inspected the button that says `"Drag an image here or browse"`, and nearby I found the element that should work:

```
<input id="sb_fileinput" class="fileinput" type="file" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg, image/png, image/webp">
```

Comment: Thanks. With your help I was able to get [working code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54230059/2829764), with the caveat that you have to click cancel at the dialog box yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The file chooser is a *OS native* control. So *Selenium* won't be able to interact with the *File Chooser Dialog* box and even through *Inspect Element* you are unable to locate it.

The reference to elements representing the file chooser dialog are only valid when the element is an `<input>` tag and the *type* attribute is set as `file` as follows:

```
<input type="file" name="myFile" accept="image/jpeg, image/png">
```

### Solution

To interact with the *OS native* *File Chooser Dialog* box you need to look for a [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/) based solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code that works based on @mblakesley's answer. I had to use Javascript to make the element in question visible to avoid an `ElementNotInteractableException` when I called `send_keys`.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.bing.com/images")

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "sbi_b")))
driver.find_element_by_id("sbi_b").click()

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "sb_brtext")))
driver.find_element_by_id("sb_brtext").click()

fileinput = driver.find_element_by_id('sb_fileinput')
driver.execute_script(
    'arguments[0].style = ""; arguments[0].style.display = "block"; arguments[0].style.visibility = "visible";',
    fileinput)
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "sb_fileinput")))
fileinput.send_keys("/sample.jpg")
```